# Accordion on hamburger (Child links not displaying)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion, hubspot

I'm trying to create an accordion which, on click, will display it's child links.

So in my demo below, on click of `parent`, I'm trying to display `child`.

```js
$(function() {

  // add icon on hamburger
  $(".hs-item-has-children").append('<i></i>');
  $(".hs-menu-children-wrapper").addClass('menu_hidden');


  // on click, check if dropdown is down already
  $(".hs-item-has-children").click(function() {

    //$('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').toggleClass('menu_is_visibile');
    if ($(".hs-menu-children-wrapper").hasClass('menu_hidden'))
      $(".hs-menu-children-wrapper").removeClass('menu_hidden');
      $(".hs-menu-children-wrapper").addClass('menu_is_visibile');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu li.hs-item-has-children i {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 16px;
  right: 50px;
  margin-top: -28px;
}

.menu li.hs-item-has-children i {
  display: block;
}


.menu li.hs-item-has-children i:before,
.menu li.hs-item-has-children i:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff6873;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
}

.menu li.hs-item-has-children i:before {
  transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu li.hs-item-has-children i:after {
  transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu li.hs-item-has-children ul.hs-menu-children-wrapper.menu_hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu li.hs-item-has-children ul.hs-menu-children-wrapper.menu_is_visibile {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
  
    <li class="hs-item-has-children" role="menu"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Parent</a>
      <ul class="hs-menu-children-wrapper menu_hidden">
        <li class="hs-menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Child</a></li>
        <li class="hs-menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Child</a></li>
        <li class="hs-menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Child</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li class="hs-item-has-children" role="menu"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Parent 2</a>
      <ul class="hs-menu-children-wrapper menu_hidden">
        <li class="hs-menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Child</a></li>
        <li class="hs-menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Child</a></li>
        <li class="hs-menu-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Child</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

It's also a HubSpot menu, so cannot alter the markup too much (which is why I'm using `.append()`)

**Edit:**

Trying to make only the selected parent links child link show. I.e. if I click `Parent 2` in the demo above, only show the child links for that `ul` (currently both open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
  $(".hs-item-has-children").click(function() {
  $(this).children('.hs-menu-children-wrapper').toggleClass('menu_is_visibile');
  });
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ukowjqav/1/

Instead of using an `if-else`, you can toggle the class itself to view each parent's children. Also note that I'm using `this`in the function. That way the code knows which particular item it is referencing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, but is there a way to only open that `li`'s child links? For example: https://jsfiddle.net/doh6Leu4/ - In this example, if I click `Parent`, only make it show the child links for that `ul`. Also tried `toggleClass` to make the list close, but doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Let me see what I can do

Comment: It did yes! Thank you

Comment: No problem, Glad I could help